# zend form dispatch a validator onblur an element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Is that possible?

I already wrote a simple validator that is triggered when the form is submitted.
Can I use the same validator, but it must be triggered right after the input field has been left.

is it possible?
pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible, here is one way to go about it.

- Add a Javascript `onblur` event to the form element
- The onblur call sends an ajax request containing that one field and its value to a ZF action
- The action calls the validator on that element, or uses `Zend_Form::isValidPartial` to check the populated element
- Return a JSON response indicating valid/invalid and optional error message
- On ajax complete, read the JSON response and update HTML to reflect the result of validation

Hope that helps.

Comment: looks great, i ll be on it. Cool :)

Comment: was great all the way to it! got helped here too, http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/using-ajax-jquery-to-validate-a-zend-form/

Answer (score 1):

This is part of working example:

Backend:

```
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    /* ... */
    public function validateAction()
    {
        if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $values = $this->_request->getParam('values');
            $form = new Form_User();
            $isValid = true;

            if (!$form->isValidPartial($values)) {
                $isValid = $form->getMessages();
            }

            $this->_helper->json(array('errors' => $isValid));
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Frontend, (just ajax call part) should be attached on event:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/user/validate/",
          data: {
            'values': $('#my-form-id').serialize()
          },
          dataType: "json",
          beforeSend:function(){

          },
          success: function(response){
            var result = response.errors;

            if (result == true) {
              // given fields are valid
              // do some extra stuff here
            } else {
              // invalid
              // do some extra stuff here
              }
            }
          }
        });
```